# How to delete lines in a file with sed which match a certain pattern and are longer or shorter than certain length

Tags: sed

I am able to delete lines with certain patterns and shorter `sed '/^.\{,20\}$/d' -i FILE` or longer `sed '/^.\{25\}..*/d' -i FILE` than certain length separately, but how do I unite pattern and length in sed?

Lines containing `A` should be between 20 and 25 characters

Lines containing `B` should be between 10 and 15 characters

Lines containing `C` should be between 3 and 8 characters

All other lines should be deleted from the file

```
1234567890 A 1234567890
12345 A 12345
1 A 1
1234567890 B 1234567890
12345 B 12345
1 B 1
1234567890 C 1234567890
12345 C 12345
1 C 1
```

So that the output should look like this

```
1234567890 A 1234567890
12345 B 12345
1 C 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you can do it with **sed**:

```
$ sed -ne '/A/ s/^\(.\{20,25\}\)$/\1/p; /B/ s/^\(.\{10,15\}\)$/\1/p; /C/ s/^\(.\{3,8\}\)$/\1/p;' file
1234567890 A 1234567890
12345 B 12345
1 C 1
```

How does it work:

```
-ne - suppress printing pattern
/A/ - look for pattern A
^\(.\{20,25\}\)$ - line with 20-25 characters
/\1/p - print pattern space
```

Answer (score 1):

Use awk and you can simply write the conditions as a boolean expression, you're not stuck trying to make a condition out of a regexp:

```
$ awk '(/A/ && /^.{20,25}$/) || (/B/ && /^.{10,15}$/) || (/C/ && /^.{3,8}$/)' file
1234567890 A 1234567890
12345 B 12345
1 C 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an `awk` solution

```
awk '/.*A.*/ && length($0) > 19  && length($0) < 26  \
 ||  /.*B.*/ && length($0) > 9  && length($0) < 16   \
 ||  /.*C.*/ && length($0) > 2  && length($0) < 9' test1.dat
```

**edit**

And here's a more efficient version, where we only get the `length($0)` one time

```
awk '{len=length($0)}
 /.*A.*/ && len > 19  && len < 26  \
 ||  /.*B.*/ && len > 9  && len < 16   \
 ||  /.*C.*/ && len > 2  && len < 9' test1.dat
```

**output**

```
1234567890 A 1234567890
12345 B 12345
1 C 1
```

I have incremented/decremented your boundary numbers by one to eliminate the need to test with `<=` and `>=` (Which are *slightly* more expensive tests. On a very large file it might cost you a 30 secs (just a guess!)).

(don't let any whitespace characters creep in after the `\` at the end of those continued lines).

(Also, you can remove that `\` chars and fold this up onto one-line if you need that.)

---

This can be enhanced to accept variable values, and I include a short example here, finishing it out to your needs can be seen as an opportunity for learning ;-)

```
awk -v lim1=10 -v lim2=26 '/.*A.*/ && length($0) > lim1  && length($0) < lim2 ...
```

Comment: consider using a variable rather than calling `length()` up to 6 times per line and all the `.*`s are doing nothing.

Comment: @EdMorton : Good idea. But don't want to spend more time on this unless I know if O.P. can use an `awk` solution. Besides, that would require using the looked-down-on form of `{ if (...) ....}` Aren't pattern/action forms to preferred ;-> ? I'll add an edit for you idea tomorrow. Good luck to all.

Comment: It'd just be a tweak to `{n=length()} /A/ && n > 19  && n < 26 || ....`.

Comment: @EdMorton : nice, I didn't realize a variable could be set in `{...}` and then used in a pattern. Will update a little later.